# How to change FSLint

Tags: default, exif

I have found FSLint, very useful lately. But there seems to be a default behavior, that I would like to avoid. If it is possible to change.

This behavior, concerns the program matching duplicate files. Which of course is what it is supposed too. My scenario involves, this program "ignoring" some image files, based on the fact that these image files containing EXIF metadata.

For example:

I have three image files that are the same, but are stored in separate directories. I know that these images are the same because I have viewed these files manually using software to view them, such as Image Viewer.

Two of these same files do not contain EXIF metadata, but one file has been updated with EXIF metadata, such as what database software like DigiKam would accomplish, using its metadata tools.

After searching, FSlint outputs listing ONLY the two matching files that DO NOT contain EXIF metadata, thereby ignoring the one image file that contains metadata, despite that file image not being a different image file likewise.

How would I change FSLint default behavior to find "ALL" image files including the files that contain updated EXIF metadata?

I again, stress that FSLint does finds duplicate files by default, and I am not reporting a program bug.

I am asking how to programmatically change FSLint default behavior.

Maybe by using FSLint Advanced search parameter?

Does the idea that Linux *find* command do something, like I have just described?

Even though I can bypass this kind of functionality, by searching using Gnome Find Files/Folders utility, I really like the fact that I can search using FSLint, and specify exact directories to search in, as opposed to Gnome's global searches which are not implicit searches.

Comment: Fslint uses hashing as [clearly described here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/fslint/master/doc/FAQ). If you need a duplicate image finder use one of those.